# JPA/EJB3 Relationship

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

I have been reading about JPA and EJB3 and would like to confirm that my understanding of their relationship is correct.  Here's what I think I know...

JPA is a specification that has been implemented by a number of vendors including:

- JBoss/Hibernate
- Oracle/TopLink Essentials (now EclipseLink)
- Apache/OpenJPA

EJB3 is a specification that is implemented in Application Servers including:

- Glassfish
- JBoss

Is this correct?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Java Persistence API introduced in Java EE 5 is a subset of EJB 3 and replaces the persistence solution of EJB 2.0 CMP. JPA 1.0 has been defined as part of the EJB 3.0 specification ([JSR 220](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220)) but can be used without and outside an EJB container. In Java EE 6, JPA 2.0 has its separate specification ([JSR 317](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317)), outside the EJB 3.1 specification ([JSR 318](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=318)). So to summarize:

- JPA is a subset of EJB 3 and implementations are provided by *persistence providers* like Toplink Essentials / EclipseLink, Hibernate, Kodo / OpenJPA (Kodo is the project from which the OpenJPA source code was derived and Kodo is now, in turn, based on OpenJPA), etc.
- EJB 3 is a wider specification and implementations are provided by the *EJB container* of application servers that rely on persistence providers:

  - The default persistence provider of GlassFish v3 is EclipseLink
  - The default persistence provider of JBoss is Hibernate
  - The default persistence provider of WebLogic 10.3.1+ is OpenJPA/Kodo or EclipseLink
  - The default persistence provider of WebSphere 6.1+ is (based on) OpenJPA

Comment: JPA being a subset of EJB3 makes sense out of why I have seen so many references where the terms are used interchangeably and the main cause of me going in circles as I tried to understand them.  Thanks!

Comment: @sdoca You're welcome. This is simplified but EJB3 has Session Beans, Entity Beans and Message Driven Beans. JPA is the Entity Beans part.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that EclipseLink is the official reference implementation for JPA 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and JPA1 and JPA2 is also implemented by [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org) which also implements JDO1, JDO2, JDO3, as well as the OGC Simple Feature spec; and is also the only truly independent implementation (not tied to a large software vendor). Obviously, users are free to slot in whichever JPA implementation they wish into their EJB3 environment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had too google OpenJPA but this is correct